# Best way to adapt vanilla site to deploy as webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment, web-applications

I've been working on a "web app" which is actually a web site at the moment, completely vanilla, made with HTML, CSS and JavaScript; absolutely no external libraries or frameworks like JQuery, React or AngularJS.

My goal is to one day deploy the site as a webapp for mobile devices (iOS and Android), and desktops (Windows and Mac).

What is the best way to do this? What path should I follow?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I guess the site could be considered an app as it is SPA due to the use of JS and almost completely responsive thanks to media queries in CSS.

The main question here is: how do I get from a website app hosted on a remote server accessed via a domain, to an installable app for mobiles and desktops (.ipa, .apk, .exe, .app, etc)?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question which is very difficult to answer in one reply. Google "cross platform app development" to get the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there are a few layers to this question. Let's start with some terms:
**Responsive web page**: A web page that works on multiple different screen resolutions (doesn't require anything more than CSS that uses media queries)
**SPA**: Single Page Application, this is how you get web "apps" rather than web pages. Tools like React and Angular help a lot with this, since you now need to manage things like state and routing (since you're not longer actually changing which page you are on).
**PWA**: Progressive Web App, this is the most modern type of web application, which tries to act very much like a native app by being capable of working without a internet connection and more.

A good way to get started down this path is to use React and their excellent tools Create React App https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app
This is a suite of tools that are already configured to create a SPA which is a PWA and with all the other modern tools you need to create a great web app. You'll need to read up on how to create Responsive web pages but there is plenty of resources for this, my tips are to start with media queries https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp as well as learning Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Okay, then I would say that my site really is an app, just as vanilla as possible.

It is in fact SPA, there is no reloading whatsoever, all thanks to some very cleanly edited JS if I may say so my self hehehe, and I am currently making it more and more responsive by using Media Queries, it's quite simple, I've got that going for me, which is nice :P

And the react part is exactly what I was looking for. So I might as well ask, are React and Angular the same sort of thing? If so which is easier to learn, and which is more widely used professionally?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be better using CSS Grids over Flexbox, that way I can completely rearrange items if I want a slightly diferent look on the mobile UI compared to the desktop version?

Thanks for the quick reply by the way, I'll be sure to check out the links!

Comment: Re: Grid vs Flexbox, depends mostly on your intended browser support, Grid is still somewhat new. But then again, progressive enhancement and graceful degradation are key ideas. If you're okay with your app looking a bit different on browsers that don't support Grid then go ahead!

Comment: Re: Angular vs React, in many ways, yes. They are both great tools to help you build complex apps. Angular is a framework (much more is included by default), while React is a library mostly for view rendering (so you'll need addons for routing, perhaps state management, etc.). Both are equally used professionally but in different areas, Angular is perhaps a bit easier to learn since everything is in the box by default but both have great communities to learn from. React is easier as a start if you only start with React and add things as you need them but it's a matter of taste as well.

Comment: It can also depend on what scale you'll build on, what other technologies you're familiar with etc.. Angular can feel very "backend-y" with it's services and dependency injection, while React is much more inspired by Functional programming and declarative code. There are plenty of articles comparing the two but each one will get the job done well, and each one can shoot you in the foot if you don't understand them. If you have no other background, my recommendation would be React, but start slow and add more only when you have the need.